# Custom listbox wont display string completly c#

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms, listbox

Hi guys I am trying to rebrush individual items in a listbox, I went with listbox draw item event, somehow it works but when I add items to my listbox, only string "b" is added and never the + "hi" part, I could write whatever I want  or add whatever I want, only string  b will be printed.

Not using draw mode and sticking with normal listbox obviously fixes the issue, so I guess it must be related to draw item event, but I cant figue out what exactly does this, I appreciate any help

```
    listBox3.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;

    private async void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string b in liIDs)
        {
            listBox3.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                listBox3.Items.Add(b + "hi");
                listBox3.Update();
            });
        }

    private void listBox3_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            e.DrawBackground();
            Brush myBrush = Brushes.White;
            myBrush = Brushes.Red;
                
            e.Graphics.DrawString(((ListBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString(),
                e.Font, myBrush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);

            e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Remove the useless BackgroundWorker (and the empty `catch` block). Make use of `BeginUpdate()` / `EndUpdate()`. Possibly, set the ListBox.DataSource to your source of data instead of adding items one by one -- You should replace `Graphics.DrawString()` with  `TextRenderer.DrawText()`

Comment: ... and never use an empty try-catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could only reproduce using items with values width larger than the list box width.
If thats the case you need to set the HorizontalScrollbar propertie to True and HorizontalExtent value

[image]